# namespace and psr-0 not working in my laravel 4 application

Tags: laravel-4, namespaces, psr-0

i have followed this tutorial http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yAzd7Ig1Wgg to get namepsaces with psr-0 working in my laravel 4 application but no joy. What im i missing?

my folder sttructure

```
>App
>>|Acme
>>>>|Billing
>>>>>>>|Billing.php
```

My billing class

```
<?php namespace Acme\Billing;    

class Billing {     
    function __construct()
    {
        dd('finally!!!');
    }
}
```

My composer file

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "app/commands",
        "app/controllers",
        "app/controllers",
        "app/models",
        "app/database/migrations",
        "app/database/seeds",
        "app/tests/TestCase.php",
        "app/lib"
    ],
    "psr-0":{
        "Acme":"app/"
    }
},
```

and my route

```
Route::get('/', function(){
    new Acme\Biling\Billing;
});
```

I keep getting this error

```
Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException
Class 'Acme\Biling\Billing' not found
```

Answer (score 1):

I found what i was missing.

```
"psr-0":{
    "Acme":"App/Acme" ***missing piece***
}
```

and this works even with psr-4. hope it helps someone.
nb: follow folder structure and check casing when naming.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run `php artisan dump-autoload` command.

Comment: I have, still no joy!